# Replace space (" ") with no space ("") in one column

Tags: mysql, string-manipulation

I have a table like this:

```
ID | Propinsi | Kota |
_________________________
 1 | Aceh     | Denpasar
 2 | Aceh     | Banda Aceh
 3 | Sumatera | Asahan
```

This table has many rows. The problem is I want to replace the space before the text in column `Kota` for all rows like this:

```
ID | Propinsi | Kota |
_________________________
 1 | Aceh     |Denpasar
 2 | Aceh     |Banda Aceh
 3 | Sumatera |Asahan
```

I searched Google, the function `replace` in MySQL only affects one row:

```
SELECT REPLACE(string_column, 'search', 'replace') as Kota
```

Can someone fix my problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

To show without space:

```
select trim(kota) from yourtable
```

To change your data:

```
update yourtable set kota = trim(kota);
```

`TRIM` function is different to `REPLACE`. `REPLACE` substitutes all occurrences of a string; `TRIM` removes only the spaces at the start and end of your string.

If you want to remove only from the start you can use `LTRIM` instead. For the end only you can use `RTRIM`.

Answer (score 9):

Run New Query in mysql

```
select REPLACE(kota,' ','') from table-name
```

this will show the result how it looks like after trimming spaces from the column and to update

```
update table-name set kota = REPLACE(kota,' ','')
```

Save.

Comment: The asker only wants to "Replace the Space berfore text on column Kota for All ROw". Your solution will replace all spaces, not just the leading ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
        /*in Sql remove extra space b/w string*/
SELECT REPLACE(@Variable, ' ', '')

        OR 

          /*in Sql remove extra space b/w string*/
        DECLARE @str varchar(150)
        SET @str='Hello    Welcome   to   stackover     flow '
        Select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@str,' ','{}'),'}{',''),'{}',' ')



    /*in c#*/
     // Mysample string
                string str ="hi you           are          a demo";

                //Split the words based on white sapce
                var demo= str .Split(' ').Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s));

                //Join the values back and add a single space in between
                        str = string.Join(" ", demo);

    //output: string str ="hi you are a demo";
```

Comment: Please explain how your query solves the author's problem; answers without explanation generally aren't received well.

Answer (score -2):

```
UPDATE yourtable SET kota = TRIM(BOTH ' ' from kota);
```

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer?